# Send picocom commands via a bash script

Tags: bash, minicom

I want to update the firmware of my device via a script using picocom commands to send the file (ymodem protocol). When I start picocom manually, with the relevant parameters (as below), it works. E.g. I can send the command via the terminal to restart the device. It works.

```
picocom /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200
```

However, when I put the same command in a bash script I get the error 'no such file or directoryACM0' when I run the script. The user has been added to the dialout and tty groups. So I am puzzled by the error. any suggestions would be helpful. I also tried minicom, but did not have much luck.

```
port is        : /dev/ttyACM0
flowcontrol    : none
baudrate is    : 115200
parity is      : none
databits are   : 8
stopbits are   : 1
escape is      : C-a
local echo is  : no
noinit is      : no
noreset is     : no
hangup is      : no
nolock is      : no
send_cmd is    : sz -vv
receive_cmd is : rz -vv -E
imap is        : 
omap is        : 
emap is        : crcrlf,delbs,
logfile is     : none
initstring     : none
exit_after is  : not set
exit is        : no

: No such file or directoryACM0
```

Here are a couple examples of the commands that I want to send:

```
command: #000C0074B0FFFF28!  
command: 1
```

Comment: You have CRLF line endings in your script; you should use a text editor that enforces UNIX line endings

Comment: Yes, thanks. I enforced the UNIX line endings and now it reads the port. I still however cannot send commands once the terminal is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try sending the commands through `picocom`'s stdin, but might have to translate explicitly the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>‑key sequences if you need them. For example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> should be translated to `0x11` (see this  [table](https://www.physics.udel.edu/~watson/scen103/ascii.html) for the other sequences):

###### Update:

An example with the given commands and a here-document would be:

```sh
picocom /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200 <<'EOF'
#000C0074B0FFFF28!
1
EOF
```

Comment: I've added a couple examples of the commands that I would like to send for updating the firmware.

Comment: I updated my answer; not sure if it'll work tough.

Comment: This is good. The first part works i.e. the HEX code restarts the device. So I lose the pico terminal and need to start another Pico term to send '1' followed by the firmware pkg file